# I would like to know why the description of the step file is changed

Tags: eyeshot

I open and use the .step file exported from eyeshot. The exported .step
file seems to change the property information as shown below.

Example:

```
 FILE_DESCRIPTION(('STEP AP214'),'1');
 ->    FILE_DESCRIPTION(('STEP AP203'),'2;1');
```

The reason I inquired about the above problem is that the specific
functions that use the file became slower as the step file was
changed.

The slowed feature is collisiondetection, a task that used to take 1 minute was not completed after an hour.

I wrote a question because the above problem was seen as a problem with the version changed during the export process.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean that the original STEP file was `AP214` and exported one is `AP203`?

Comment: Yes, this is why the exported file is changed to AP203.  Additionally, I am using build 592 of eyeshot 2021 version.